# C++ DLL: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, dll

I seem to have some issues with creating new files for my project.

The issue is that in my `sk_error.h` file it seems to complain about `unresolved external symbols` (full error report below). When I place my `OutOfRange` class in my `sk_interface.h` file no one complains but when I put the class in the errors file it has issues with it.

If I was to comment out `OutOfRange` it works perfectly fine so I dont think that it is an issue with the DLL setup.

**sk_error.h**

```
#include <sk_platform.h>
#include <sk_interface.h>

namespace sky {
    class SK_API OutOfRange : IError {
    public:
        OutOfRange() {
            m_message = " Out Of Range";
            m_value = (0 << 1);
        }
        std::string getMessage() override {
            return m_message;
        }
    };
}
```

**sk_platform.h**

```
#if defined (SK_NONCLIENT_BUILD)
        #ifndef SK_API
            #define SK_API __declspec(dllexport)
        #endif
    #else
        #ifndef SK_API
            #define SK_API __declspec(dllimport)
        #endif
#endif
```

**sk_interface.h**

```
#include <sk_platform.h>
#include <string>

namespace sky {

    ...

    class SK_API IError {
    public:
        virtual std::string getMessage() = 0;
    protected:
        uint32_t m_value = 0;
        std::string m_message = "Error not initialized";
    };

}
```

**The Client Project using the DLL**

```
#include <sk_logmanager.h>
#include <sk_error.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sky::g_LogManager.startup();
    sky::OutOfRange err;
    std::cout << err.getMessage() << "\n";
    sky::g_LogManager.shutdown();
    while (1) {}
}
```

**Error Output**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SkyTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sky::OutOfRange::OutOfRange(void)" (__imp_??0OutOfRange@sky@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall sky::OutOfRange::getMessage(void)" (__imp_?getMessage@OutOfRange@sky@@UAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sky::OutOfRange::~OutOfRange(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRange@sky@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Game Development\DevEnv\SkyTest\Debug\SkyTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "SkyTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit:

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (could be the source of the error). The Client Project is using the .lib file.

Comment: *The Client Project using the DLL* -- DLL's are not used at all in the build process.  What **is** used is the `*.lib` file that was created.  Nowhere do you mention this, as this is the file the linker is looking for.

Comment: `I dont think that it is an issue with the DLL setup` your error is due to the definitions of `OutOfRange()`, `~OutOfRange()`, `getMessage()` _not_ being linked properly. Could you tell us how you are linking the DLL? And of course what IDE, etc. you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unresolved external is always a link error. It even has it in its name: LNK2019.

It is telling you it cannot find the implementation for sky::OutOfRange::OutOfRange()

You have it in a header somewhere and you've called it, but you have not linked to the library that implements it.

We have no way of telling you what library implements it or where it lives on your hard drive. You will have to consult the documentation for OutOfRange, the author of it, or yourself.

I can tell you that you will want to check:
right click the executable project->

properties->linker->general->additional library directories
properties->linker->input->additional dependencies

and make sure the path to the library that defines OutOfRange is in the former and the library name is in the latter.

EDIT: If the library itself has a header that imports it, as it appears from the code you posted, you just need to set up the additional directories part.

In the end, you have to consult the documentation for whatever library you are using or hit up their forums.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this may be related to your solution configuration and solution platform. It wasn't working for me, when I set my solution configuration to "Debug" and platform to "x64"; it started working after setting it to Release - x86